# Bootstrap tooltip not hiding after drag and drop event

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cwgofr84/1/

with the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hover 1">Hover over me 1</button>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hover 2">Hover over me 2</button>

  <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hover 3">Hover over me 3</button>
</div>
```

where I have three buttons, if I drag one of the buttons so the tooltip displays and then drop and then hover over a different button, it doesn't hide the first tooltip and displays the second. like so:

[image]

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change your script to:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
});
```